# Unable to mount data directory in MSSQL RC1 server setup in linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to change the default data directory for MSSQL Server RC1 2017 after installation and setup in linux (Ubuntu-16.10).

I used the following command to set the default data directory. Then restarted the mssql server.

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set filelocation.defaultdatadir /mnt/var/opt/mssql/data/

systemctl restart mssql-server.service
```

After this I tried to create a simple database "test"

```
sqlcmd -s localhost -U sa -P "someStrongPassword" -Q "CREATE DATABASE test"
```

The error returned is as follows:

> MODIFY FILE encountered operating system error 31(A device attached to
>   the system is not functioning.) while attempting to expand the
>   physical file '/mnt/var/opt/mssql/data/test.mdf'. 
>     CREATE DATABASE
>   failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related
>   errors.

The error log indicates an OS error:

> /mnt/var/opt/mssql/data/test.mdf: Operating system error 31(A device
>   attached to the system is not functioning.) encountered.

I cannot mount  the data directory by any means. The permissions to "/mnt" directory are set to 777 too. Changing the default data directory  to any other folder, works perfectly fine. Is this a known or recent bug with mssql server?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an issue with using remote storage through NFS and SMB that came up in CTP 2.1 and was not yet fixed in RC1.  See release notes:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes#a-idrc1-rc1-july-2017-a
The only workarounds are to use local storage or CTP 2.0.  We are working on a fix.  Release ETA is TBD ATM.